# How to go back to note in OneNote after opening a webpage?

Tags: software-installation

I am using ubuntu 20.04.2 lts and install OneNote on the ubuntu store.
After I click a link to open a webpage, there is no way (figure attached) to go back to the note page. I have to reinstall it to reset the OneNote.
Does anyone know how to go back to the notes without reinstalling it?
Thanks
[Figure. After clicking a link in a note, it go to a website and there is no way to go back to the note page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqrq7.png)

Comment: I will use the web OneNote directly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can simply remove "lastlink" record in `~/snap/onenote-desktop/13/.config/OneNote/config.json`, and then restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

Close OneNote. Remove the folder `~/snap/onenote-desktop/13/.config/OneNote`. (Or replace the version 13 with your version.) Restart OneNote. You will have to login again with your credentials.

Comment: is there any other way? it works but still I need to do this every time after clicking links in onenote
thanks